# Tesseract unable to read simple number

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I have this image[image: this image] and I need tesseract to read the value.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

im = cv2.imread("num.png")
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(im))
```

It does not print anything. Am I doing something wrong since it is pretty clear that it is a 7.

Even after scaling the image up by 5x with intercubic it still would not work. This is the image now [image]

Comment: Please read through [Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html), especially the options regarding the [page segmentation method](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method). `pytesseract.image_to_string(im, config='--psm 6')` works perfectly fine, even on the small image.

Answer (score 4):

As described [here](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method):

> By default Tesseract expects a page of text when it segments an image. If you’re just seeking to OCR a small region, try a different segmentation mode, using the --psm argument.

In this case,  `--psm` from 6 to 10 should work fine. Example:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(im, config='--psm 6')
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is correct. I think that image of 7 is not clear enough for pytesseract. You need to preprocess the image. [This link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/getting-started-with-tesseract-part-ii-f7f9a0899b3f/) might help.

Comment: I tried using the scale with intercubic and I edited the post to show what it looked like. Now it definitly looks like a 7 but it will still not detect it.